# IntelliJ setting for package structure

Tags: intellij-idea

I am working a Java project, and when I set up my project, I set up a number of packages, like this:

[MySetup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDtg9.png)

But I would like to set it up like this:

[Intended set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBKt4.png)

I know there is a setting from right-click project/Mark as Directory, I've tried all of them, bar the test directories. How would I set this up for the intended set up? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck the 'Flatten Packages' option and enable 'Compact Middle Packages' in the cogwheel menu drop-down:

[image]